# Multithreaded grouping algorithm

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, algorithm, grouping

I have a collection of circles, each of which may or may not intersect one or more other circles in the collection. I want to group these circles such that each "group" contains all circles such that every member of the group intersects at least one other member of the group, and such that no member of any group intersects any member of any other group. I have come up with the following VB.NET/pseudocode algorithm to solve this problem on a single thread:

```
Dim groups As New List(Of List(Of Circle))
For Each circleToClassify In allCircles
    Dim added As Boolean
    For Each group In groups
        For Each circle In group
            If circleToClassify.Intersects(circle) Then
                group.Add(circleToClassify)
                added = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If added Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not added Then
        Dim newGroup As New List(Of Circle)
        newGroup.Add(circleToClassify)
        groups.Add(newGroup)
    End If
Next
Return groups
```

Or in English

1. Take each item from the collection of circles
2. Check if it intersects with any member of any existing group *(Bear in mind a "group" may only contain a single circle)*
3. If the circle does intersect in the aforementioned manner add it to the appropriate group
4. Otherwise create a new group with this circle as its only member
5. Go to step 1.

**What I want to be able to do is perform this task using an arbitrary number of threads.** However, I haven't got very far at all as all solutions I've come up with so far will just end up executing serially due to locking.

Can anyone provide any tips on what I want to be thinking about to achieve this multithreading?

Comment: Perhaps ask this on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't appear to handle the case: 1 overlaps 2, 3 overlaps 4, 5 overlaps 1 and 3, which would join the two groups created thus far.

Comment: There are also more efficient algorithms than intersecting every circle every time, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm.

Comment: @IanMercer Good spot, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR

- The best multithreaded solutions avoid sharing or perform read-only sharing. (And hence don't need locks.)
- Consider partitioning your work so that threads don't share result data, and then merging each thread's results.
- Note that when you strip away the detail of detecting whether groups of circles intersect, you are really dealing with a connected components graph theory problem. There's plenty of useful material on this subject online. And in fact you may find it much easier and sufficiently fast to simply apply a breadth first search algorithm to find connected components.

---

## Detail

When doing multi-threaded development, first prize is to implement the threads in such a way as to minimise the number of locks. In the most trivial case: if they don't share any data, they don't need locks at all. However, if you can guarantee that the shared data *won't be modified* while the threads are running: then you don't need locks in this case either.

In your question, there's no need for your input list of circles to be modified. The problem you have is that you're building up a *shared* list of circle groups. Basically you're sharing your result space and need locks to ensure the integrity of the results.

One technique in this situation is to "partition and merge". As a trivial example consider finding the maximum of a large list of numbers. The naive (and ideal single-threaded solution) is to:

- keep a single "current maximum" found;
- compare each element to this value;
- and ***update*** the "current maximum" if it's higher.

The problem for multithreading occurs in updating of the shared result. One solution is to:

- partition the list for each of `p` threads;
- find the maximum *within each partition*;
- once all threads finish their work, the final result is trivially obtained by finding the maximum of the `p` partitioned maximums.

The trade-off against a single-threaded solution involves weighing up the ease with which the workload can be partitioned and the per-thread results merged versus the often much simpler single-threaded approach.

---

## Applying *partition and merge* to circle clusters

> As a side note: Observe that your question is essentially a graph theory question such that: Each circle is a node; where if any 2 circles intersect, there's an undirected edge between them; and you're trying to determine the connected components of the graph.
> Obviously this provides an area that you can research for more ideas/information. But more importantly it makes easier to analyse the problem with simple boolean assessment of whether 2 circles intersect.
> *Also note the potential performance improvements by first pre-processing your circles into a suitable graph structure.*

Assume you have 8 circles (A-H) where 1's in the table below indicate the 2 circles intersect.

```
 ABCDEFGH
A11000110
B11000000
C00100000
D00010101
E00001110
F10011100
G10001010
H00010001
```

One partitioning idea involves determining what's connected by only considering a subset of circles and all their immediate connections.

```
 ABCDEFGH
A11000110   p1 [AB]
B11000000
---------
C00100000   p2 [CD]
D00010101
---------
E00001110   p3 [EF]
F10011100
---------
G10001010   p4 [GH]
H00010001
```

**NB** Even though threads are sharing data (e.g. 2 threads may consider the intersection between circles A and F concurrently), the share is read-only and doesn't require a lock.

Assume 4 partitions (and 4 threads) of `[AB][CD][EF][GH]`. Connected components per partition would be broken down as follows:

```
[AB]: ABFG
[CD]: C        DFH
[EF]: ADEFG
[GH]: AEG      DH
```

You now have a list of potentially overlapping connected components. Merging involves iterating the list to find overlaps. If found, take union of the 2 sets is a new connected component. This will finally produce: ABFGDHE and C

Some optimisation techniques to consider:

- The bottom left of the matrix mirrors the top-right. So you should be able to avoid duplicating processing of the inverse connections.
- The merging of partitions can itself be partitioned and merged.
- In fact in the extreme case you could start out partitioning a single circle per partition.

```
Connected(A) = ABFG
Connected(B) = B
    Connected(AB) = ABFG
Connected(C) = C
Connected(D) = DFH
    Connected(CD) = C,DFH
        Connected(ABCD) = ABFGDH,C
Connected(E) = EFG
Connected(F) = F
    Connected(EF) = EFG
Connected(G) = G
Connected(H) = H
    Connected(GH) = G,H
        Connected(EFGH) = EFG,H
            Connected(ABCDEFGH) = ABFGDHE,C
```

> **Very NB** You need to ensure appropriate selection of data structures and algorithms or suffer extremely poor performance. E.g. A naive intersection implementation might require O(n^2) operations to determine if two intermediate connected components intersect and totally destroy your goal that lead to all this additional complexity.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to divide the image into blocks, run the algorithm for each block independently, on different threads (*i.e.* considering only the circles whose center is in that block), and afterwards join the groups from different blocks that have intersecting circles.

Another approach is to formulate the problem using a graph, where the nodes represent circles, and an edge exists between two nodes if the corresponding circles are intersecting. We need to find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) of this graph. This disregards the geometric aspects of the problem, however, there are general algorithms which may be useful (*e.g.* you could consider the last slides from [this link](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~vs3/comp422/lecture-notes/comp422-lec24-s08-v2.pdf)).